# Trying to find Top 10 products within categories through Regex

Tags: regex, e-commerce

I have a ton of products, separated into different categories.
I've aggregated each products revenue, within their category and I now need to locate the top 10.

The issue is, that not every product have sold within a given timeframe, or some category doesn't even have 10 products, leaving me with fewer than 10 values.

As an example, these are some of the values:

1. 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,3,5,6,20,46,47,53,78,92,94,111,115,139,161,163,208,278,291,412,636,638,729,755,829,2673
2. 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,124,158,207,288,547
3. 0,0,90,449,1590,10492
4. 0
5. 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,7,12,14,32,32,37,62,64,64,64,94,100,103,109,113,114,114,129,133,148,152,154,160,167,177,188,205,207,207,209,214,214,224,225,238,238,244,247,254,268,268,285,288,298,301,305,327,333,347,348,359,362,368,373,402,410,432,452,462,462,472,482,495,511,512,532,566,597,599,600,609,620,636,639,701,704,707,728,747,768,769,773,805,833,899,937,1003,1049,1150,1160,1218,1230,1262,1327,1377,1396,1474,1532,1547,1565,1760,1768,1836,1962,1963,2137,2293,2423,2448,2451,2484,2529,2609,3138,3172,3195,3424,3700,3824,4310,4345,4415,4819,4943,5083,5123,5158,5334,5734,6673,7160,7913,9298,9349,10148,11047,11078,12929,18535,20756,28850,63447
6. 63,126

How would you get as close as possible to capturing the top 10 within a category, and how would you ensure that it is only products that have sold, that are included as a possibility? And all of this through Regex.

My current setup is only finding top 3 and a very basic setup:

- Step 1: `^.*\,(.*\,.*\,.*)$` finding top 3
- Step 2: `^(.*)\,.*\,.*$` finding the lowest value of the top 3 products
- Step 3: Checking if original revenue value is higher than, or equal to, step 2 value.
- Step 4: If yes, then **bestseller**, otherwise just empty value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using regex? regex does not seem like an optimal solution to this problem

Comment: So `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` are categories and comma separated numbers are products? The products seem to be ordered by their ID and I don't see a revenue figure. Please clarify.

Comment: Why does zero repeat so many times?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 1-6 are the categories yes, and the comma separated numbers are the revenue of each product. This is also why 0 repeats so may times, because its the revenue of a specific product, and that product haven't sold in the given timeframe.

Comment: @depperm And I am using regex, because it is the only flexible solution, my system allows me to use. I am able to do multiple regex rules in session, just as illustrated in my 4 steps.

Comment: So you want to retrieve up to the last 10 revenues per line, ignoring zero revenue? See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a programming language so I'm going with Javascript here but this regex is quite compatible with almost any regex flavor:

```perl
(?:[1-9]\d*,){0,9}[1-9]\d*$
```

- `(?:[1-9]\d*,){0,9}` - between 0 and 9 times, find numbers followed by a comma; ignore zero revenue
- `[1-9]\d*` - guarantee a non-zero revenue one time
- `$` - end line anchor

https://regex101.com/r/1xBQD3/1

---

If your data were to have leading zeros like `0,0,00090,00449,01590,10492` for some reason then you would need this regex which is 33% more expensive:

```perl
(?:0*[1-9]\d*,){0,9}0*[1-9]\d*$
```

Comment: Good solution to a strange problem... this assumes no sales numbers ever starts with a 0, which is true in OP's sample data, but not necessarily guaranteed. I'd be inclined to allow it, for robustness, and use `(?:0*[1-9]\d*,){0,9}0*[1-9]\d*$`, i.e., add `0*` in front of `[1-9]`, to accept `0100,234` and `100,234` as equivalent.

Comment: @joanis Thanks! I guess I was just feeling lazy.  `\d*` would have the same effect as `0*`, right?

Comment: Not quite: your use of `[1-9]` is important here since OP wanted only items with sales >0.

Comment: @joanis The required `[1-9]` would enforce that though. At any rate I tried `0*` and it results in 33% (11,000) more steps if you switch to PHP at regex101. However, the `\d*` results in catastrophic backtracking so I'm just going to leave my answer as-is =)

Comment: @joanis When I said `\d*` I meant `(?:\d*[1-9]\d*,){0,9}\d*[1-9]\d*$`

Comment: Oh, I see. I still vote for `0*[1-9]\d*`, because that's more efficient: it avoids backtracking because there's only one way to match any given number, whereas `\d*[1-9]\d*` can match the middle part to any of the non-zero digits in each number. As a general rule, REs that can only match things in one way are better, in that they're more efficient, and don't risk catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @joanis OP's data does not have leading zeros so I'd like to maintain my original savings of 11,000 steps =)

Comment: @joanis `0*[1-9]\d*(?=(?:,\d+){0,9}$).*` would be a less expensive way of doing things https://regex101.com/r/AOxkAw/1 =)

Comment: I'm willing to believe that, although this has the same number of backtracking points, so it won't make a huge difference.

Comment: @joanis The new way is about 21,000 steps versus 39,000 for the old one

Comment: I had not noticed the step count on regex101 before, that's a really nice feature. Thanks for pointing it out. Here's a slight variant with only 19k step: `0*[1-9]\d*(?:,\d+){0,9}$`, which just removed the look-ahead. Of course, this problem would be so much more efficiently solved with split and array operations, but OP didn't want that.